# how to make the content script append html to the original opened web page in google chrome extension v3

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension

I am using google chrome extension v3 to write a plugin. Now I want to append the html content that contains a popup window to the source web page. This is the v3 manifest conifg:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content/index.js"]
    }
  ],
```

and this is the `content/index.ts` file looks like:

```
fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL('/content/template.html')).then(r => r.text()).then(html => {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
    // not using innerHTML as it would break js event listeners of the page
});
```

and this is the `/content/template.html` content:

```
<div>dddddd</div>
```

but I found the content script append the template html content to the google chrome extension plugin popup poge, not the original website page. For example, when I opened the stackoverflow, I want the html content append to the stackoverflow page.why did this happen? what should I do to fix it?

Comment: It means your popup.html loads content.js. Don't do it.

Comment: How to avoid this problem?@wOxxOm

Comment: Just don't do it. Remove content.js from your popup.html.

Comment: Ok, I found the output file packed by webpack contains content.js in the index.html, I did not know where add this import.@wOxxOm